# How to understand what property is necessary for the primitiveness of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Under what condition the group $G=\langle a,b\rangle$, where $a=(i,j),g=(1,2,\ldots, n),$ will be primitive.
I considered some properties, such as $g \cdot g$ is equal to the shift of the bottom line in a two-line entry by $2$ and $g \cdot g\cdot g$ equals a shift of $1$. But it seems to me that sorting through all possible variants of the multiplication $a$ and $b$ is not the best option. Maybe I should use the proof of the Jordan's theorem ($G \lt S(\Omega)$ and $G$ contains a transposition $(\alpha , \beta) \in G \Rightarrow G = S(\Omega)$)?

Comment: What do you mean by a “primitive group”? This doesn’t seem like a standard definition…

Comment: Presumably you discuss [primitivity of the action of $G$ on $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveGroupAction.html)? Anyway, if $d=\gcd(j-i,n)>1$, won't the action of $G$ then preserve the partition into residue classes modulo $d$?

Comment: @Aphelli,Sorry if I didn't put it right, but G is primitive if it acts transitively on X and the only partitions the G-action preserves are the trivial partitions into either a single set or into |X| singleton sets. Otherwise, if G is transitive and G does preserve a nontrivial partition, G is called imprimitive.

Comment: And on the other hand, if $\gcd(j-i,n)=1$, won't the 2-cycles $g^kag^{-k}$ then generate all of $S_n$ much the same way that the 2-cycles $(12), (23),\ldots,(n-1;n)$ do?

Comment: I suspect we have covered this already. Feels like a standard exercise about the primitivity of a group generated by an $n$-cycle and a $2$-cycle. It rings a bell anyway :-)

Comment: @AdamJensen The good news is that you can edit your question to make it clearer, instead of writing the explanations in the comments !

Comment: Primitivity is certainly a completely standard property of permutation groups.

Comment: It's primitive if and only if $|j-i |$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, please, can you explain more about this property or where can I deduct this from?

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, this group is primitive if and only if $\gcd(|j-i|,n) = 1$. Let's assume that $j>i$.

Suppose first that $\gcd(j-i,n) = d > 1$ and let $e=n/d$. Then you can check that both generators preserve the block system $$\{\, \{1,d+1,2d+1,\ldots,(e-1)d+1\},\,
\{2,d+2,2d+2,\ldots,(n-1)d+2\}, \cdots, \{d,2d,3d,\ldots,n\}\,\},$$
so it is imprimitive (in fact $a$ fixes all of the blocks, and $b$ permutes them in a cycle of length $d$).

Conversely, if $\gcd(j-i,n) = 1$, then $b^{j-i}$ is an $n$-cycle that maps $i$ to $j$, and so $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle a,b^{j-i} \rangle = S_n$, which is primitive.